# Using MapboxNavigation iOS with Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, mapbox, xcode10

Is there any possibility to use `MapboxNavigation` (version `0.21` or `0.22`) iOS with Xcode 10. On its Github and CocoaPods site is stated, that it can only be used with Xcode 9, but a few issues on Github mention the (successful) use of Xcode 10 with `MapboxNavigation`.

However, I tried to install `MapboxNavigation` via CocoaPods using Xcode 10 and get a bunch of errors:

```
/Users/Paul_Obernolte/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pq-app-v2-gynuaxsohvqddqegrvemywowchkr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MapboxDirections.swift/Swift Compatibility Header/MapboxDirections-Swift.h:171:9: error: 'MapboxDirections/MapboxDirections.h' file not found
#import <MapboxDirections/MapboxDirections.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'MapboxDirections'
```

Is there any workaround to avoid this errors using Xcode 10?

Edit: Here is my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'

EXPO_CPP_HEADER_DIR = 'ExpoKit'

target 'pq-app-v2' do
  pod 'MapboxDirections.swift', '~> 0.23'
  pod 'MapboxMobileEvents',
    :git => 'https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-events-ios.git',
    :commit => "79d29f1df5a9187481f5c9ac8fa13430d1f04139"
  pod 'MapboxNavigation', '~> 0.21.0'

  ... (more Pods)

end
```

I need to download `MapboxMobileEvents` separately because of this issue: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-events-ios/pull/85

Comment: I’m using MapboxNavigation 0.22 with Xcode 10 (latest public release 10.1 I think) and apart from about 6 deprecation warnings for some Mapbox files it all works fine with no workarounds needed. Could you show your podfile?

Comment: I've updated my question and added my Podfile to it...

Answer (score 0):

```
target 'pq-app-v2' do

   use_frameworks!

   ... (more Pods)

end
```

change code in pod file if "use_frameworks!" is commented than put it uncommented as above.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code only answer are usually not of high quality. It's best practice to add a few lines of explanation to aid in the learning of others. For more help formulating an answer, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) out.